# Magento1.9.4: Images Not Uploading in Admin – JSON in Syntax Error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, image-upload, json

I am trying to upload an image - something which I have done a hundred times. Now it gets stuck with "uploading..." showing.

- I have tried disabling extensions.
- I haven't made any changes.
- There have been no updates.
- The images is 1.00mMb
- I have checked for existing zero sized images
- I have tried multiple browsers
- I have reindexed and cleared the cache
- I have tried incognito mode

The Error I get in console is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at String.parseJSON [as evalJSON] (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:720)
at klass.onFileSuccess (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:22344)
at d.<anonymous> (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:391)
at d.<anonymous> (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:21540)
at k (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:21540)
at d.fire (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:21540)
at e.chunkEvent (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:21540)
at f.event (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:21540)
at XMLHttpRequest.doneHandler (30fee76906a26cc4fffab3ed736897bb.js:21540)
```

For some reason, The strings "anonymous" is being parsed which is creating an error. I'm not sure the problem is specific to the uploader.

Comment: Check in console network, after uploading image you would getting error in ajax response. Please check response and share error here

Comment: Shaoib - it's in the original question above! Or do you mean something else - please explain?

Comment: The error you are getting in console is not the actual error, it is showing it because some ajax is not responding properly. You can check actual error in exception.log or in ajax response.

Comment: Thanks Shoaib - where do I find the response.? And the log?

Comment: in console, open Network tab, clear previous log and upload image, you will see ajax sending requiest, open that request and get response from response tab. But first check var/log/exception.log see if you are getting any error in it.

Comment: empty exception.log file first, then upload image, and then see which error you are getting in exception.log.

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11912 bytes) in /home/fineand1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php on line 101

Comment: I guess you have used `print_r` on object that why you are getting this error

Comment: Shoaib - sorry, you are speaking to a Magento Novice! How do I fix it...

Comment: Use `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` in `index.php` and in `pub/index.php`

Comment: Cool - that worked. Thanks for your help @ShoaibMunir

Comment: I am adding this in answer, please mark it correct so that it would be helpful for others in future

Comment: @ShoaibMunir ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); is not working for me, checked in console the ajax response returns to login page. In log i got Not valid template file:adminhtml/base/default/template/system/config/system/storage/media/synchronize.phtml
 Not valid template file:frontend/base/default/template/configurableswatches/catalog/media/js.phtml

do you have any suggestion for it

Answer (score 2):

As instructed by @ShoaibManir I added this code to index.php:

```
Use ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

...to fix my problem. Although the images was a 1Mb file, I have since noticed that reducing the image resolution (to 1000 x 1000) also worked without the code added.

Thanks chaps.
Kevin

Comment: Good to hear that. +1 on your answer, please mark my answer correct if it is helpful to you

Comment: I will do - but cannot for 48 hours

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments you are getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11912 bytes) in /home/fineand1/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php on line 101
```

to fix this please use `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` in `index.php` and in `pub/index.php`

this is not a good way, but your issue will resolve after this